# DataGridViewComboBoxCell datasource empty

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have a `DataGridView` with a column as a `ComboBox`
This is the code I use to create my columns and then update the `DataSource` for every row.

```
var dTable = new DataTable();
dTable.Columns.Add("Id",typeof(int));
dTable.Columns.Add("Desc", typeof(string));

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   var dRow = dTable.NewRow();

   dRow[0] = i;
   dRow[1] = "test";
   dTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;

//Create the ComboBoxColumn at the end of the grid
var cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cmb.Name = "ComboCol";
cmb.HeaderText = "ComboCol";

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);

UpdateDataSourceCombo();

private void UpdateDataSourceCombo()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
       var comboCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ComboCol"];
          //Same datasource for every row just for testing
       comboCell.DataSource = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
    }
}
```

The column is correctly created as a `ComboBox` but it's always empty.

**UPDATE**
After further testing I know that the problem occurs only when I use a datasource for the entire DGV.

It works fine if I just create the column myself:

```
var test = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        test.Name = "asd";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(test);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());

        var cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cmb.Name = "ComboCol";
        cmb.HeaderText = "ComboCol";

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);

        UpdateDataSourceCombo(); //Same function as the original post
```

I updated the original code with a sample of the loading of the datatable into the grid.

Comment: It works fine here. Note that while the dropdown is filled the values won't show unless the cell.Value is in the items list! Also: You need to set the DGV datasource before setting the Items' data sources. Btw, why `i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1`?? Shouldn't the last row also have the dd items filled??

Comment: Not sure what to make of the update. After each setting of the DGV.DataSource you need to set the ITems, which makes sense especially since you want each to have a row-depended list of data..

Answer (score 0):

Works on my project like this :
Create a class for the source arrays.
Set the DisplayMemberPath an the ValueMemberPath properties of your combobox column.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace sof
 {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=testBase;Integrated security=true"))
        {
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter sqlAdp = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM City WHERE City_Name LIKE 'Chalon%'", sqlConn))
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                sqlAdp.Fill(dTable);
            }
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;

        //Create the ComboBoxColumn at the end of the grid
        var cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cmb.Name = "ComboCol";
        cmb.HeaderText = "ComboCol";


        cmb.DisplayMember = "Display";
        cmb.ValueMember = "Value";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);

        UpdateDataSourceCombo();


    }
    private void UpdateDataSourceCombo()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            var comboCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ComboCol"];
            //Same datasource for every row just for testing
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                comboCell.DataSource = new customObj[] { new sof.customObj("a", "a"), new sof.customObj("b", "b"), new customObj("c", "c") };
            else
                comboCell.DataSource = new customObj[] { new sof.customObj("1", "1"), new sof.customObj("2", "2"), new customObj("3", "3") };
        }
    }

}

class customObj
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public customObj(string value, string display)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.Display = display;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: This works but I need to have a different datasource for every rows of my grid. As I said in the code i used the same datasource just for testing.

Comment: which type of data do you try to add ? Allways the same things ? Because your code work when I try.    if(i % 2 == 0)
                comboCell.DataSource = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
                else
                    comboCell.DataSource = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };

Comment: I see datas in the combobox.